# How to vmap over specific funciton in jax?

Tags: python, jax

I have this function which works for single vector:

```
def vec_to_board(vector, player, dim, reverse=False):
    player_board = np.zeros(dim * dim)
    player_pos = np.argwhere(vector == player)
    if not reverse:
        player_board[mapping[player_pos.T]] = 1
    else:
        player_board[reverse_mapping[player_pos.T]] = 1
    return np.reshape(player_board, [dim, dim])
```

However, I want it to work for a batch of vectors.

What I have tried so far:

```
states = jnp.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]])
 batch_size = 1
b_states = vmap(vec_to_board)((states, 1, 4), batch_size)
```

This doesn't work. However, if I understand correctly vmap should be able to handle this transformation for batches?

Comment: The problem here is that `jnp.argwhere` calls `jnp.nonzero` that returns an array which size depends on the concrete values of your input tensor `vector`. Therefore you can't use Jax transformation that require static shapes (see [here] https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.nonzero.html).

Comment: Awesome, I went through the docs, and thats actually the case. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues you'll run into when trying to `vmap` this function:

1. This function is defined in terms of numpy arrays, not jax arrays. How do I know? JAX arrays are immutable, so things like `arr[idx] = 1` will raise errors. You need to replace these with equivalent JAX operations (see [JAX Sharp Bits: in-place updates](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#in-place-updates)) and ensure your function works with JAX array operations rather than numpy array operations.
2. Your function makes used of dynamically-shaped arrays; e.g. `player_pos`, has a shape dependent on the number of nonzero entries in `vector == player`. You'll have to rewrite your function in terms of statically-shaped arrays. There is some discussion of this in the [`jnp.argwhere` docstring](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.argwhere.html); for example, if you know *a priori* how many True entries you expect in the array, you can specify the `size` to make this work.

Good luck!